# How to calculate intensity inhomogeneity based on average filter by matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a question about intensity inhomogeneity. I read a paper, it defined a way to calculate the intensity inhomogeneity based on average filter:
[image]

Let see my problem, I have a image I (below code) and a average filter with r=3. I want to calculate  image transformation J based on formula (17). Could you help me to implement it by matlab code? Thank you so much.

This is my code

```
%Create image I
I=[3    5   5   2   0   0   6   13  1
0   3   7   5   0   0   2   8   6
4   5   5   4   2   1   3   5   9
17  10  3   1   3   7   9   9   0
7   25  0   0   5   0   10  13  2
111 105 25  19  13  11  11  8   0
103 105 15  26  0   12  2   6   0
234 238 144 140 51  44  7   8   8
231 227 150 146 43  50  8   16  9
];
%% Create filter AF
size=3;    % scale parameter in Average kernel
AF=fspecial('average',[size,size]); % Average kernel
%%How to calculate CN and J 
CN=mean(I(:));%Correct?
J=???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close! The mean intensity is calculated correctly; all you are missing to calculate J is apply the filter defined with fspecial to your image:

Here is the code:

```
clc
clear

%Create image I
I=[3    5   5   2   0   0   6   13  1
0   3   7   5   0   0   2   8   6
4   5   5   4   2   1   3   5   9
17  10  3   1   3   7   9   9   0
7   25  0   0   5   0   10  13  2
111 105 25  19  13  11  11  8   0
103 105 15  26  0   12  2   6   0
234 238 144 140 51  44  7   8   8
231 227 150 146 43  50  8   16  9
];

% Create filter AF
size=3;    % scale parameter in Average kernel
AF=fspecial('average',[size,size]); % Average kernel

%%How to calculate CN and J 
CN=mean(I(:)); % This is correct

J = (CN*I)./imfilter(I,AF); % Apply the filter to the image

figure;

subplot(1,2,1)
image(I)

subplot(1,2,2)
image(J)
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Comment: +Vote 1 for great answer. However, Let see the definition of AF filter. Is it correct with this code AF = imfilter(Img,fspecial('disk',sigma),'conv','replicate');

Comment: Great glad to help! And yes your filter is correct.